# How to loop from paginated JSON response with offset in laravel with progress bar ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, progress-bar, offset

I'm working with an api that returns a result in a paginated format. first result will have 100 records. But I am stuck on how to do the next loop and concatenate the result from the first records. Below is my code. I am using Laravel framework

```
$response = Http::withBasicAuth('myusername','mypassword')->get('http://api.sample.com/users');
return $response->json();
```

The results of the above code is

```
{
  "total": 5000,
  "offset": 0,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

this will be stored as a json file to be downloaded after all records has been fetched.

I really don't have idea how to implement the second loop and integrate with progress bar to show the percentage. hope someone could give an idea

Comment: What does api.sample.com docs say: how pagination is made?

Comment: Hi @Tpojka in order to get the next records will need to append at the end of the url something like `?offset=100`

Comment: Ok. I don't see any part of code where it stopped. Check of [how to write perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You have to isolate part of code which makes bug/error and post it here. Otherwise I can't see how anyone can assume what you have there or what is going on.